# React-Redux: mapStateToProps not updating with individual properties, but does connect when I map entire state/store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I map a state to props for a specific component, the individual props don't seem to update even though the state changed. And when I map the entire state to the component, I get the behaviour I want (because the state has changed).  See below.

```
const Dashboard = ({ state, justMarkets, justItems }) => {
  console.log('state', state);
  console.log('state markets', state.markets);
  console.log('just markets', justMarkets);

  console.log('state items', state.items);
  console.log('justItems', justItems)
  const markets = state.markets, 
        items = state.items;
  return (
    <div>
      {
        markets
           .filter(market => market.hasItems)
           .map(market => {
                const { 
                    marketname: name, 
                    id, 
                    Products, 
                    Address, 
                    GoogleLink 
                } = market;

                return (
                    <div className="market" key={id}>
                      <div>
                        <h1>{name}</h1>
                        <h2>{Address}</h2>
                        <a href={GoogleLink} target="_blank">View in Google Maps</a>
                      </div>
                      <Items items={items} products={Products} />
                   </div>
                );
            })
         }
      </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ 
     state, 
     justMarkets: state.markets, 
     justItems: state.items 
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Dashboard);
```

If you see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkYAC.png), you will notice that when the state is updated, I can only access the updated state from within the component with `state.markets` and `state.items`. I can't seem to get access to them directly in the `mapStateToProps` (both `justMarkets` and `justItems` remain empty arrays after state is updated).  Would appreciate any insight into this matter!!!

Comment: Seems pretty odd. Is it possible that you're accidentally overwriting the props somewhere else? I mean if you for some reason has code like `<Dashboard  justMarkets={ [] } justItems={ {} } />`.

Comment: I figured it out!  I forgot that redux shallow checks.  In the reducer, I had return Object.assign(state, newPropObj) instead of Object.assign({}, state, newPropObj), so technically it was as if the pointer to the state object had never changed.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh, I see. Tricky! Nice that you found the bug! I recommend that you post that as an answer and (after 48 hours) accept your own answer, for future readers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out!  The problem was actually in the reducer.  In the reducer, my code was written as:

```
return Object.assign(state, action.propObj)
```

when it should have been

```
return Object.assign({}, state, action.propObj)
```

Ahh, semantics.  I thought Object.assign returned a new object on its own, but, having read the docs, I now know that it returns the first argument.

So this was essentially a classic mutability bug.  I was overwriting the properties of the state object and returning the previous state with the updated property.  As redux shallow checks for changes and the pointer to the state object had not changed, my state updates were not being registered in the mapStateToProps, but I could access the property directly off the state in my component.

Comment: Thanks bro... this thing was killing me